# Which font is shown in the Visual Studio 2015 OS X sample code?

Tags: font

What is the name of this font shown in Visual Studio 2015 for OS X?

[image: Visual Studio 2015 Mac sample code]

Answer (score 1):

That's probably the font Monaco !

It was used by Xcode and Terminal prior to Snow Leopard as the was the default monospaced font.

Answer (score 0):

It's Monaco, a monospaced font included with OS X.

http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/ is an excellent way to identify fonts by screen shot (not fool-proof but pretty good).